# Android.Location vs. Accelerometer

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, accelerometer

i'm looking for the best way to implement a road navigator that gets the velocity, distance between 2 points using the smartphones techniques.

through my searches i found 2 different tech. using either the **accelerometer** or **android API (android.Location)**.

some opinions said that using accelerometer wont give me an accurate results because there will be so much noises as a bumpy roads, buildings...etc and calculations will be so complex.

on the other hand using the Android API (android.Location) means i should always be connected to the GPS, doesn't that affect on the battery?!! and as i found i can't open the GPS by myself i used always ask the user for a permission(so boring). and is there an limitation

So kindly help to take a decision, is it useful to be connected 24 hours on GPS in order to update the device location.. or to use the accelerometer??

Comment: Mmm, accelerometer will give you your location? I don't think so. This is a strange question. Please somebody bring light here

Comment: GPS is much simpler, you can always get absolute location in the open air. Using accelerometer, you get relative location to the previous, and that may cost you a lot of time to debug and tune but still not accurate at all. The answer is obvious.

Comment: accelerometer would give me the speed of the device!! i put in the title that i want to get the velocity and location.. so which tech, is better to use if i want to get the velocity. @joaquin did you get my point??

Comment: What? What velocity? Will you register absolutely all the movements of the device? Accelerometer won't give you the position of the device in the world. It'll give you the coordinates of his current rotation state. I mean you'll know if the device is quiet, is horizontally or vertically placed... Little things, man!

Comment: And you don't need to care about the device battery. Google play services did that for you. Don't use android location api, use Google play location services instead

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should use `GPS`. The battery will be strained but you get much more accurate result. `Sensor` should be used only when `GPS` is not available and for a short distance.

Using `GPS` you can call `location.hasSpeed()` and if positive call `location.getSpeed()` together with `getBearing()` will give you the `velocity`.